# Looping Through And Editing UITextField Placeholder Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a `UIView`, within the `UIVIew` I add a `UIScrollView` that contains another `UIView` and a list of `UITextFields`. I am using the following code to try and loop through all the views and select the `UITextfields`. The problem is that although the loop is happening the It is not finding any of the `UITextfields`.

```
- (void)styleUITextFields {

for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;

        // Do whatever you want with the text field.
    }

}
```

This is how I add the `UIScollView` to the `UIView`

```
- (void)addForm {

[self styleSegmentController];
[self styleUITextFields];

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

[self.scrollViewForm setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, self.scrollViewForm.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollViewForm setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 56, screenWidth, screenHeight - 56)];

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollViewForm];

}
```

Any suggestions as to why this might not be working.

Comment: Where is the code you put the uiview and its textFields inside the `scrollViewForm`?

Comment: You call `styleUITextFields` again if the view is a `UITextField`? Are you sure? Wouldn't you want to call itself if it's not a `UITextField`

Comment: Sorry it was a bad paste job on my part, the example is now corrected above. The styleUITextFields is actually inside the "addForm" method.

Comment: In terms of the UIScrollView that is actually created in Storyboards.

Comment: So where is the recursion part? or there is none? I mean `styleUITextFields` will loop to the subviews of the main view subviews (the scrollview). you need a nested loop to loop through the scrollview subviews.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense now. So my original code will only loop through the child views of the self.view and not their subviews as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)styleUITextFields:(UIView*) view {

    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;

            // Do whatever you want with the text field.
        } else { // look insde the subview for more views.
           [self styleUITextFields: subview];
         }

    }


- (void)addForm {

    [self styleSegmentController];
    [self styleUITextFields: self.view];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    [self.scrollViewForm setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, self.scrollViewForm.frame.size.height)];
    [self.scrollViewForm setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 56, screenWidth, screenHeight - 56)];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollViewForm];

}
```

Comment: Sorry it was a bad paste job on my part, the example is now corrected above. The styleUITextFields is actually inside the "addForm" method

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your view hierarchy is *self.view -> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UITextFields*. In this case the for loop on `[self.view subviews]` will not give you `UITextField`s as they are not direct subviews of self.view.

You should iterate though subviews of subviews till you find `UITextField`s and then modify them as required.

This can be done through

```
- (void)styleUITextFieldsInSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return;

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {

            // Do whatever you want with the text field.

        } else {

            // Iterate the subviews of subview
            [self styleUITextFieldsInSubviewsOfView:subview];
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method by initially passing `self.view`. 
So in place of your `[self styleUITextFields];` you would call

```
[self styleUITextFieldsInSubviewsOfView:self.view];
```